# Need to convert a string to int in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to pass in url parameters to a django template like this...

```
response = render_to_string('persistConTemplate.html', request.GET)
```

This the calling line from my views.py file.  persistConTemplate.html is the name of my template and request.GET is the dictionary that contains the url parameters.

In the template I try to use one of the parameters like this...

```
{% for item in (numItems) %}

  item {{item}}

{% endfor %}
```

numItems is one of the url parameters that I am sending in my request like this...

```
http:/someDomain/persistentConTest.html/?numItems=12
```

When I try the for loop above, I get an output like this....

> image 1 image 2

I am expecting and would like to see the word image printed 12 times...

> image 1 image 2 image 3 image 4 image 5 image 6 image 7 image 8 image 9 image 10 image 11 image 12

Can anyone please tell me what I am going wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason you're doing this in a template and not in a view?

Comment: Well, I was trying to follow the whole layered approach but perhaps as others have suggested the best place to handle this is in the view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the place for this is in the view.

I feel like the above example won't work -- you can't iterate over an integer.

```
numItems = request.GET.get('numItems')

if numItems:
   numItems = range(1, int(numItems)+1)

return direct_to_template(request, "mytemplate.html", {'numItems': numItems})


{% for item in numItems %}
 {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I get the same result when I try it this way.... image 1 image 2

Comment: Can you post your code? This code works. I noticed a slight mistake where I wrote `range(1, int(range)+1)` which should be `range(1, int(numItems)+1)` (this should have thrown an exception if you tried to run it anyways. If 'numItems' is passed into GET, create a list of integers from 1 to `numItems`, and iterate over them in the template.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 29, in ?
    pprint(persistentConTestPage(req))
  File "views.py", line 18, in persistentConTestPage
    return direct_to_template(request, "persistConTemplate.html", {'numItems': numItems})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/simple.py", line 16, in direct_to_template
    c = RequestContext(request, dictionary)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.update(processor(request))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/core/context_processors.py", line 34, in debug
    if settings.DEBUG and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:
AttributeError: 'mockHttpRequest' object has no attribute 'META'

Comment: I am getting the error above when I try to compile locally.  I think that this may be why I am seeing the same result as before.  I think my views.py file is not getting compiled...

Comment: I've gone ahead and tested this in a live environment: if you literally copy and paste this code (importing direct_to_template -- point is you can use whichever form of httpresponse you wish), define a mytemplate.html, and load it you will get the results you are looking for. Sorry I can't help you with that error.

Comment: OK thank you Yuji so very much for all your help.  I will see if I can get it working and let you know how it goes. -John

Comment: OK so I finally figured out what the trouble is...  When you call request.GET.get you have to supply a default value like this... request.GET.get(numItems, 10)  Otherwise you get an non type exception.  Now the code you supplied above is working for me.  Thank you so so much for working with me...

Comment: Ah, glad you got it working! I'm confused why request.GET.get('numItems') would cause a problem, since {}.get will return None if the key fails, and django templates silently fail something like iterating over None.

Comment: Well, I think it's because I am so new at this.  I was compiling it locally and not supplying a value for the parameter like the URL would when you pass it in from the response object.  Therefore it was trying to supply a default value which was not present and I was getting a NoneType error.  Also it his just for those who try this after me if any one hits this tread for a similar reason, I am using render_to_string instead of direct_to_template.

Answer (score 146):

you can coerce a str to an int using the add filter

```
{% for item in numItems|add:"0" %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add

to coerce int to str just use slugify

```
{{ some_int|slugify }}
```

EDIT: that said, I agree with the others that normally you should do this in the view - use these tricks only when the alternatives are much worse.

Comment: Thank you. I got a headache working with forms. The catch was in "foreignkey" field. When loaded from DB "form.<field>.value" contains integers. But after submiting "form.<field>.value" are strings.... TADÁ!

Comment: instead of doing list comprehensions on ids... neat. so simple.

Comment: It seems `slugify` works for me. Now I am just wondering what's the meaning of that word. Slugify is not in my vocabulary nor in my dictionary.

Comment: On django 1.8, **add:"0"** worked for me, **slugify** didn't.

Comment: After using `floatformat` and `intcomma`, `add` is just appending a `'0'`

Answer (score 39):

I like making a custom filter:

```
# templatetags/tag_library.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def to_int(value):
    return int(value)
```

Usage:

```
{% load tag_library %}
{{ value|to_int }}
```

It is for cases where this cannot be easily done in view.

Comment: This is way cleaner that the other answers.

Comment: it says unresolved library.. where to put template tags folder?

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to do this is using inbuilt **floatformat** filter.

For Integer

```
{{ value|floatformat:"0" }}
```

For float value with 2 precision

```
{{ value|floatformat:"2" }}
```

It will also round to nearest value. for more details, you can check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat.

Answer (score 2):

You should add some code to your view to unpack the GET params and convert them to the values you want.  Even if `numItems` were an integer, the syntax you're showing wouldn't give you the output you want.

Try this:

```
ctx = dict(request.GET)
ctx['numItems'] = int(ctx['numItems'])
response = render_to_string('persistConTemplate.html', ctx)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I get the following error when I try this...    ctx['numObjects'] = int(ctx['numObjects'])
KeyError: 'numObjects'

Comment: Wrap that line in `if 'numObjects` in ctx:`

Answer (score 1):

In my case one of the items was a string and you can not compare a string to an integer so I had to coerce the string into an integer see below

```
{% if questions.correct_answer|add:"0" == answers.id %}
    <span>Correct</span>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that: if "select" tag used.

```
{% if i.0|stringformat:'s' == request.GET.status %} selected {% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution is kind of a hack and very specific..

In the template I want to compare a percentage with 0.9, and it never reaches 1, but all the values are considered string in the template, and no way to convert string to float.

So I did this:

```
{% if "0.9" in value %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

If I want to detect some value is beyond 0.8, I must do:

```
{% if ("0.9" in value) or ("0.8" in value) %}
...
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

This is a hack, but suffice in my case. I hope it could help others.