# Is there a filter for divide for Django Template?

Tags: python, django

I noticed there is  built-in `add` filter, but I wasn't able to find `divide`.

I am new to Django and not sure if there is a such filter.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There is not it. But if you are a little hacker....

[http://slacy.com/blog/2010/07/using-djangos-widthratio-template-tag-for-multiplication-division/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160525152906/http://slacy.com/blog/2010/07/using-djangos-widthratio-template-tag-for-multiplication-division/)

> to compute A*B: {% widthratio A 1 B %}
>
> to compute A/B: {% widthratio A B 1 %}
>
> to compute A^2: {% widthratio A 1 A %}
>
> to compute (A+B)^2: {% widthratio A|add:B 1 A|add:B %}
>
> to compute (A+B) * (C+D): {% widthratio A|add:B 1 C|add:D %}

Also you can create a filter to division in 2 minutes

Comment: That's an interesting use of the widthratio tag, but, it could certainly leave someone scratching their head trying to figure out what it's doing, imo.

Comment: Thanks. But this gives `Caught TypeError while rendering: float() argument must be a string or a number` error for some numbers

Comment: Link fixed, sorry for the downtime. :)

Comment: The content should be put on on the answer anyway, even with a link. :)

Comment: Now you have a summary in the answer

Comment: Keepin mind that `widthratio` returns a string that you need to convert to an integer for it to work in comparisons for example. One good way of doing that is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7405779/5421745

Comment: Link is broken again; "content should be put on on the answer anyway, even with a link. :)"

Comment: @RickDavies the content is  in the answer. The link had the next info: to compute A*B: {% widthratio A 1 B %} \n to compute A/B: {% widthratio A B 1 %} ...

Comment: @Goin well, the link is 404 (and apparently has been before), so maybe cruft it?

Comment: @RickDavies and the author (slacy) fixed it in the past. For me it is a must when I copy something I always type the reference. I answered this question, but I only copyed and pasted  the info. For me it is right.

Answer (score 34):

1. Create a `templatetags` package within your Django app: `my_app/templatetags/__init__.py`
2. Create a module within `templatetags` with the following code:

```
# my_app/templatetags/my_custom_filters.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def divide(value, arg):
    try:
        return int(value) / int(arg)
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return None
```

3. In your template, add the following, replacing `my_custom_filters` with the module name in step 2:

```
{% load my_custom_filters %}

{{ 100|divide:2 }}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/ for more information

Comment: You should manage the case of floating number, it could be useful some time :-)

Comment: It could be division by zero, so I would suggest:
 `def divide(value, arg): return (int(value) / int(arg)) if int(arg)!=0 else 0 `

Comment: It would be really helpful if you showed how to actually use the filter.

Comment: Don't forget to restart server after tag creation.

Answer (score 15):

There is a Python module to do math operations in your templates: [Django-Mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters).

It contains `add` as you said, but also `div` to divide:

```
 8 / 3 = {{ 8|div:3 }}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use a custom template, but if you don't want to you can use the widthratio built in tag,

```
{% widthratio request.session.get_expiry_age 3600 1 %}
```

Another example

```
{% widthratio value 1150000 100 %}
```

Syntax:

```
{% widthratio parm1 parm2 parm3 %}
```

So basically its used for scaling images, but you can use it for division. What it does is: parm1/parm2 * parm3.

Hope this helps, more on widthratio [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the percentage already calculated like in your question, you can use this tag to calculate the percentage in the template from the original value and total value against which your percentage is calculated. It does the job if you only need an integer percentage without precision:

```
{% widthratio value total_value 100 %}
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#widthratio

Answer (score -2):

You can use `divisibleby`

> Returns True if the value is divisible by the argument.
>
> For example:
>
> `{{ value|divisibleby:"3" }}`
>
> If value is 21, the output would be True.

You can see [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)