# Calculate two values and calculate difference in percentage in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

My online marketing department uploads analytical statistics on our marketing programs and we've always kept records in Excel.  I've built an application to replace Excel and highlighting cells and adding functions to them was easy. The only thing I can't figure out is how to calculate and display the difference from one query to another.  I apologize if I am not asking it correctly, I've included as image to help explain.  Ultimately I would like to use a custom filter that will know how to calculate similar objects.  All the code I looked at to try and figure it out is still a bit over my head.  Any assistance or push in the right direction would be awesome.  Thank you.

**My View**

```
t_2014 = traffic.filter(created__year='2014')
...

wd1 = t_2014.filter(created__week_day=1).aggregate(Sum('sessions'), Sum('new_users'), Sum('reminder'), Sum('campaigns'), Sum('new_sales'), Sum('sales_renewals'))
wd2 = t_2014.filter(created__week_day=2).aggregate(Sum('sessions'), Sum('new_users'), Sum('reminder'), Sum('campaigns'), Sum('new_sales'), Sum('sales_renewals'))
...

t_new_sales_2014_wd1 = wd1.get('new_sales__sum')
t_new_sales_2014_wd2 = wd2.get('new_sales__sum')
...
```

**My Template**

```
<td>{{ t_new_sales_2014_wd1 }}</td>
...
<td>{{ t_new_sales_2014_wd2 }}</td>
...
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: You can write a template tag to accept the two (or however many) values, do the comparison and output the value in the template. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @brandon said, you may create custom [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags). (however you should not be using them a lot, this logic should be in views and templatetags slows down page speed).
Here are few tags that you might use in your case:

---

**1. Multiple filters/tags**
I guess, first you need to divide both values to get difference:

```
@register.filter
def divide(value, arg):
    try:
        return float(value) / float(arg)
    except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return None
```

But instead of custom tag you may use built-in [`withratio`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447913/is-there-a-filter-for-divide-for-django-template).
Another useful tag/filter for you is `percent`

```
@register.filter
def percent(value):
    if not is_number(value):
        return None
    return floatformat(Decimal(value) * Decimal(100.0), 2) + '%'
```

Where `is_number()` is my custom code to test if string (or number) can be a number.

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return False
```

and may be `add_color`:

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=False)
def add_color(value):
    if float(value) > 0:
        return '<font color="#28a901">%s</font>' % value
    elif float(value) < 0:
        return '<font color="#f63434">%s</font>' % value
    else:
        return str(value)
```

In template just use something like:

```
{{ t_new_sales_2014_wd1|add:-t_new_sales_2014_wd2|divide:t_new_sales_2014_wd2|percent|add_color }}
```

But using too many filters might be a problem and I can not simply tell what code does.

---

**2. Single filter/tag**
May be you should create just one filter/tag and use it. Like this:

```
@register.filter
def difference(value, arg):
    try:
        result_num = (float(arg) - float(value)) / (float(arg) * 0.01)
        if result_num > 0:
            result = '<font color="#28a901">%s%%</font>' % result_num
        elif result_num < 0:
            result = '<font color="#f63434">%s%%</font>' % result_num
    except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return None
    return result
```

and in template just use (replace `l` and `e` for your variables):

```
{{l|difference:e|safe}}
```

Either use `safe` in template or disable autoescape in template tag like I did in `add_color`.

Comment: Thank for the detailed post.  I am kind of following the logic here, but when implementing it, I am getting a `Could not parse some characters: t_new_sales_2014_wd3|-t_new_sales_2014_wd2| | divide:t_new_sales_2014_wd3 | percent | add_color` error in the browser.  I am still learning Python so not exactly sure where to identify the error and the browser error doesn't give too many clues.

Comment: Subtract in template is not allowed. You can add another filter for subtract or create new. I'll post you a filter later if you still need it, I dont have time right now.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out a while back. So I am doing the division in the view but when trying to add the `percent` filter, I get a `is_number` not defined.  I can add `floatformat:"2"` directly in template and it works, but I would rather use the `percent` so I can keep my template and view clean from repetitive code. I'll keep banging away at it, but if you have any clue on the `is_number` not defined error, that would help.  So far this solution is working out great and taught me some new tricks.

Comment: is_number is my custom method, that is why you get an error (sorry, I should have mentioned it). Added to answer. Also, check my second part of answer, only one tag is used.

Comment: Awesome!! Much better! Thank you.