# How to check if for loop is in the middle value

Tags: python, html, django

I have trouble getting the middle loop in a forloop in django template.

I've tried using

```
{% for value in key.dictionary %}
    {% if forloop.counter == widthratio value|length 2 1 %}
```

but with no effect. Actually after the `widthratio` I get an error `Expected %}`

Computing the division was taken from this post [Is there a filter for divide for Django Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447913/is-there-a-filter-for-divide-for-django-template)

Comment: `value` is one key in the dictionary, so it's length would be entirely the wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`widthratio` is not a filter, it's a *tag*. But you can assign the result of `widthratio` to a variable using `as`:

```html
{% widthratio key.dictionary|length 2 1 as midpoint %}
{% for key, value in key.dictionary.items %}
    {% if forloop.counter == midpoint|add:"0" %}
```

`widthratio` produces a string, so in order to test equal with an integer `forloop.counter` value, we have to convert `midpoint` back to an integer too, using the [`add` filter as a work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template).

Note that we take the length *of the dictionary*, not of a single key. I also opted to loop over the dictionary items (key and value) in the above example.

Demo:

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("""\
... {% widthratio foo|length 2 1 as midpoint %}
... {% for key, value in foo.items %}
...     {% if forloop.counter = midpoint|add:"0" %}Half-way through!{% endif %}
...     {{ forloop.counter }}: {{ key }} == {{ value }}
... {% endfor %}
... """)
>>> context = Context({"foo": {"spam": 42, "vikings": 17, "eggs": 81}})
>>> print(t.render(context))



    1: spam == 42

    Half-way through!
    2: vikings == 17


    3: eggs == 81
```