# How do I use operators in Django {% if %} template tag?

Tags: django

so I'm trying to do simple calculation as my condition statement in {% if %}{% endif %} tag in Django. But somehow it doesn't work. Here's my code :

```
{% for i in range %}
{% if i/2 != 1 %}
<!- Do something ->
{% elif i/2 == 1 %}
<!- Something else ->
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I keep getting error that says "Could not parse the remainder: '/2' from 'i/2'" 
So there must be another way of using the operators in if statement, but I can't figure out what that is. 
I would very much appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a filter for divide for Django Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447913/is-there-a-filter-for-divide-for-django-template)

Comment: [This](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/) should help