# How to iteratively render the first X fields in a Django form

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm rendering a form in a Django html template by using a `for` loop and iterating over the fields. I want to add some sections & headers inside my form, so is there a way to 'slice' the form fields or otherwise iteratively display only a subsection of fields?

Something like

```html
{% for field in form.slice(0, 5) %}
<!-- render first 5 fields -->
<h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>Some text about next section</p>
{% for field in form.slice(5, 10) %}
<!-- render the next 5, etc. -->
```

I know the worst case answer is to render each field manually, but it's a VERY long form. Here's my existing form code.

```html
      {% for field in form %}
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="{{field.id_for_label}}">
          {{field.label}}
        </label>
        <div class="control">{{field}}</div>
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{field.help_text}}</p>
        {% endif %}
        <ul class="errorlist">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
          <li class="is-danger help">{{error}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Django `forloop.counter0` or `forloop.counter` variables. The first one which keeps track of the iteration inside the loop starting with index 0 and the second one indexes iterations starting with 1 (see the bottom of this section see the bottom of this section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for for more):

```
    {% for field in form %}     
      {% if forloop.counter0 == 5 %}
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>Some text about section 2</p>
      {% elif forloop.counter0 == 8 %}
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>Some text about section 3</p>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="{{field.id_for_label}}">
          {{field.label}}
        </label>
        <div class="control">{{field}}</div>
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{field.help_text}}</p>
        {% endif %}
        <ul class="errorlist">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
          <li class="is-danger help">{{error}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

You would still have to manually check for the values. If you want for example to add section content in a way you can iterate the content every 5 fields you can take advantage of [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) and [`Django-Mathfilters`](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/) to divide:

```
    {% for field in form %}     
      {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:5 %}
        <h2>Section {{ forloop.counter0|div:5}}</h2>
        <p>Some text about section {{ forloop.counter0|div:5}}</p>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="{{field.id_for_label}}">
          {{field.label}}
        </label>
        <div class="control">{{field}}</div>
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{field.help_text}}</p>
        {% endif %}
        <ul class="errorlist">
          {% for error in field.errors %}
          <li class="is-danger help">{{error}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

For more references you can see [Modulus % in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494209/modulus-in-django-template) to know about `divisibleby` and [Is there a filter for divide for Django Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447913/is-there-a-filter-for-divide-for-django-template) to get some other methods on how to divide numbers in your Django template!

Comment: Oh this is great, had no idea forloop.counter existed. Exactly what I needed!