# Checking against a unicoded list of strings in template

Tags: django

I have the following code in my template (please note the `if` statement):

```
{% for base in bases %}
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input name="base" value={{ base.id }} type="checkbox" 
           {% if base.id in selected_bases %}checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
        <span>{{ base.name }}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

The `selected_bases` variable is a list of unicoded strings: `[u'3', u'1', u'5']`.
`base.id` is an integer.

How can I make them the same type so that `if` statement does what I need it to?

Comment: Can you pass `selected_bases` from the view as integers?

Comment: @aganders3: I'd rather not. `selected_bases` is the list of bases that get passed back and forth `selected_bases = request.GET.getlist('base')`. @gruszczy's solution below does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this work, but try this:

```
{% if value|stringformat:"d" in selected_bases %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this in the view instead, but you can pipe the list values through the [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter, which does type coercion - or pipe the ints to `slugify`, which will do the reverse. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template).