# Django template tag IF not returning what is expected

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following in my template

```
{% for excursion in excursions %}
    {{ excursion.pk }}-{{ formset.excursion.value }},
        <input type="radio" id="id_excursion_{{ excursion.pk }}" name="excursion" value="{{ excursion.pk }}"{% if formset.excursion.value ==  excursion.pk %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
        <label for="id_excursion">{{ excursion.name }}</label>
        {{ excursion.short|safe|linebreaksbr }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

template print: 1-1,1-3,

formset.excursion.value is 1
excursion.pk = 1 and 3 (2 objects)
```

My view:

```
def edit(request, uuid):
    confirm = None
    instance = get_object_or_404(Foo, uuid=uuid)
    formset = FooForm(instance=instance)
    excursions = Excursion.objects.filter(is_activity=False)

    context = {
        'excursions':excursions,
        'formset':formset, 
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = FooForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if formset.is_valid():
            form = formset.save()
            confirm = 'true'

            context =  {
                'excursions':excursions,
                'formset':formset, 
                'confirm_create':confirm
            }

    return render(request, "edit.html", context)
```

This works as its supposed to when I navigate to this page, BUT when I submit the form, and render the page again after the submit, it does not return TRUE again, even though the values are still there, the same as before?

*I thought perhaps is is because the one value is a string and the other an int? But this does not seem to make a difference when putting the values in quotes*

I even tried the **ifequal tag** but it does the same

Comment: That might be issue in your view when the value is passed. Show us that view as well. Also, try printing both values in template.

Comment: There you go, you'll see they are the same values

Comment: What happens if you pass both values to the slugify filter? See topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template

Comment: I first thought `formset` was a formset, but obviously it is not.

Comment: Slugify worked! So it must be some string int thing?

Comment: No, `formset` here is a form. That's unnecessarily confusing.