# Converting amount to lakh and crore

Tags: django, django-models, templatetags

How to convert amount to [lakh and crore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) in django. for example if amount is 100 000 I want to show 1 Lakh. Is it possible to do this by using a custom template tag?

I'm a beginner so this is the code I wrote to get this done. But how to use this in template tag?

```
if properties.expected_price >= 100000:
    expected_price_in = expected_price/100000
elif properties.expected_price >= 1000000:
    expected_price_in = expected_price/1000000
else:
    expected_price_in = expected_price
```

Comment: May be helpfully this url : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template

Comment: Small note: your code will never enter the `elif`

Comment: I couldn't find anything helpful in that link :(

Comment: I think, being kind, that you need to go do the Django tutorial, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can find good explanation of Django custom template filter [here](http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/).
I'll just give you a brief description.
First of all you need to creat folder templatetags inside your django app and add `__init__.py` file.
Create in new folder some .py file for example `custom_filters.py` with following content:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def num_format(value):
    if value >= 1000000:
        return value/1000000
    elif value >= 100000:
        return value/100000
    else:
        return value
```

Now you can use it in template like this:

```
{% load custom_filters %}
{{ your_number|num_format }}
```

But I also suggest you to look at [humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/humanize/) utils. Propably it can solve your problem.

just add into settings INSTALLED_APPS 'django.contrib.humanize' and try this in template:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ your_number|intword }}
```