# Django template if statement return wrong value

Tags: django, python-2.7, web, django-templates, django-views

In my home page I have blog, on the right side there is Posts category list like:

- Sports
- Crime

and etc.. I try to make that when I'm in certain category that active category button will be highlighted.
I'm doing that by setting GET parameter to my home page like: **/?category=1**

NOW... In index.html template I'm doing this:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    {{ category.pk }} != {{ request.GET.category }} // This is for debugging. Returns 1==1
        {% if category.pk == request.GET.category %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'web_serv:index' %}?category={{ category.pk }}">{{ category }}<span class="pull-right">({{ category.post_set.count }})</span></a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="active"><a href="{% url 'web_serv:index' %}?category={{ category.pk }}">{{ category }}<span class="pull-right">({{ category.post_set.count }})</span></a></li>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But this is not working. Any suggestions how to solve this, maybe there is another way?

***EDITED:***

I figured that category.pk returns int and request.GET.category returns string. Next question. How to convert int<==>string, so I could compare them?

Comment: Try using this approach to convert the string to int http://stackoverflow.com/a/4831735/977593

Answer (score 0):

It worked by doing this:

```
{% if category.pk != request.GET.category|add:"0" %}
```

apparently |add:"0" converts string to int.