# How to convert the data types in the django templates language?

Tags: python, django

This is the code of `home.html`:

This code is in my `views.py`:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'age':'27'})
```

This is the templates html `home.html`:

```
<td>
      {% if age > 25 %}
      <span>abc</span>
      {% elif age > 30 %}
      <span>def</span>
      {% elif age > 35 %}
      <span>ghi</span>
      {% else %}
      <span>others</span>
      {% endif %}
</td>
```

You know in the `home.html`, it will be `others`, not `abc`.

How to convert the string to int in the django templates language?

Comment: Convert it in Python: `return render(request, 'home.html', {'age': int('27')})` or something similar.

Comment: It's not a "Python" templates library - it's **django**'s templates...

Comment: python has more than one templating language — this looks like jinja2?

Comment: Why not just pass it as an int in your views?

Comment: You can coerce it AFAIK but it would be better to do it in the view. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template