# Could not parse the remainder: '(len(seasons))' from 'range(seasons)'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a var with the name 'seasons' that returns the number of seasons in a tv show and I know for a fact it does work and it returns it.

but I'm trying now to loop through it so if a tv show has 6 seasons it echos:

- season1, season2.. etc

but it doesn't work.

code :

```
{% for season in range(seasons) %}
  <li rel="p{{season}}" class="activate-panel">الموسم {{ season }}</li>              
{% endif %}
```

reference to how I got the number of seasons from db:

I've an Episode model that has a field with the name season_number, so for order to get the higest season number I searched for the episode with the highest season number

```
latest_episode = Episode.objects.order_by('-season_number').filter(is_published=True, tvshow=tvshow).first()
```

then I get the season with

```
seasons = latest_episode.season_number
```

and it does return a number indeed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your Django Model and Views code to your question so we can see how you are generating the `seasons` variable.

Comment: You cannot use `range()` in templates. Check out [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107737/numeric-for-loop-in-django-templates) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template) for workarounds.

Comment: @tatlar hey thanks for caring i did edit the question hope its more clear now. :)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: yes I used the range methond inside the views.py instead of the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
{% for season in seasons %}
  <li rel="p{{season}}" class="activate-panel">الموسم {{ season }}</li>              
{% endfor %}
```