# Django template check value with URL parameter

Tags: python, django, templates, url

I'm trying to create a select in html to list all month and the default value of the select should be equal to the month parameter from the URL

My URL :

> /list-working-session/?month=7&year=2019

month and year are the parameter

in My HTML:

```html
<select name="month" class="form-control" id="month" required>
  {% for i in months %}
    {% if i == request.GET.month %}
      <option value="{{ i }}" selected="selected">{{ i }}</option>
    {% else %}
      <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

months is the context from the view with range(1,13) and i managed to list from 1 to 12 in select option but i can't get the IF condition to work so the default select value equal to the month in the URL.

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.GET.month is a string and is being compared with an integer. You will have to convert them to common type to get desired result

Please see [Need to convert a string to int in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template)

Comment: i see that why it doesn't work. i changed by using add filter after the value request.GET.month|add:"0" and it worked

Comment: Did you also try using int(request.GET.month) instead?

Comment: int() can't be use in template, i tried it and got the error Could not parse the remainder: '(request.GET.month)' from 'int(request.GET.month)'