# String to Integer in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have rendering one string in django template but in django template, I want to convert it into integer. I have tried many thing like |add:to_int but it doesn't work.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15820445

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to convert a string to int in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template)

Answer (score 3):

@Vaibhav Mishra,

Does it work for you? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add

Like:  `{% value|add:"0" %}`

If it does not work for you: then create a custom template filter and register it:

```
YOUR_APP_FOLDER/
__init__.py
models.py
templatetags/
    __init__.py
    your_app_name_extras.py [any valid filename.py]
views.py
```

in **your_app_name_extras.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def to_int(value):
   return int(value)
```

In your template file, you need to put the code:

```
{% load your_app_name_extras %}
 {{ value|to_int }}
```

**For more details:**

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

[Need to convert a string to int in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template/15820445#15820445)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```
{% if string_value == int_value|stringformat:'s' %} {% endif %}
```