# How to avoid THOUSAND SEPARATOR in certain views in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using Django's THOUSAND SEPARATOR in the settings.py file for the entire project but due to this whenever the IDs of objects get greater than 1000 in my views e.g: 1200, they are read as 1.2 . How to avoid the THOUSAND SEPARATOR for certain views?

Comment: Do the opposite, use [intcomma from humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#intcomma)?

Comment: Or try to [coerce the integer to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template)