# Django template language if tag not working

Tags: python, django

I have a django template with an update form, for an invoices application.
I want to allow to update the record after it was saved.
One of the model fields is manager which is a foreign key:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True ,blank=True)
```

The problem is that I don't to display the manager's user id, but his/her first name, so I want to populate the select tag with all manager's first name. I have tried this:

```
<select id="id_manager" name="manager">
   {% for manager in managers %}
     {{ manager }} || {{ initial_manager }}
     {% if manager == initial_manager %}
          <option value="{{ manager.user.id }}" selected>{{ manager.user.first_name }}</option>
     {% else %}
          <option value="{{ manager.user.id }}">{{ manager.user.first_name }}</option>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This is the views.py part:

```
managers = Profile.objects.filter(Q(role = 'manager') | Q(role = 'cfo') | Q(role = 'ceo') | Q(role = 'sec'))
projects = Project.objects.all()
form = InvoiceForm(instance = invoice)
initial_manager = invoice.manager
return render(request, "invoice/update.html", {'form': form, 'managers':managers, 'projects':projects, 'initial_manager':initial_manager})
```

I have added this to see the values of the variables:

```
{{ manager }} || {{ initial_manager }}
```

and I see for example " 102 || 102 ", which means that they are equal but the if part doesn't run, it always goes to the else part. It doesn't matter what I've tried, I have tried passing initial_manager as a string, comparing manager to " 102 " or to "102" or 102, but nothing works.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to use {{ manager.id }}.

Comment: @ilsurealism thanks, but it didn't help. I've also tried manager.user.id which gives me 102 (which is the correct id in my check) that equal to the initial manager nad still doesn't work

Comment: Check the data types of the variables. Maybe they are different.

Answer (score 1):

if both are the same value but it's returning false when using if
then try modify the code to make them both float using
[floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat)
for your case

```
 {% if manager|floatformat:"0" == initial_manager|floatformat:"0" %}
      <option value="{{ manager.user.id }}" selected>{{ manager.user.first_name }}</option>
 {% else %}
      <option value="{{ manager.user.id }}">{{ manager.user.first_name }}</option>
 {% endif %}
```

this will make them both float with 0 decimal so it's like converting them into an integer.
[see this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831306/need-to-convert-a-string-to-int-in-a-django-template)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, no change

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I've used stringformat instead of floatformat.

```
<select id="id_manager" name="manager">
   {% for manager in managers %}
   {{ manager }} || {{ initial_manager }}
   {% if manager|stringformat:'s' == initial_manager|stringformat:'s' %}
        <option value="{{ manager.user.id }}" selected>{{ manager.user.first_name }}</option>
   {% else %}
        <option value="{{ manager.user.id }}">{{ manager.user.first_name }}</option>
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Now it works. I appreciate your help